# Porting code from lucene to elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

I have to following simple code that I want to port from lucene 6.5.x to elasticsearch 5.3.x.

However, the scores are different and I want to have the same score results like in lucene.

As example, the idf:

Lucenes *docFreq* is 3 (3 docs contains the term "d") and *docCount* is 4 (documents with this field). Elasticsearch has 1 *docFreq* and 2 *docCount* (or 1 and 1). I am not sure how these values relate to each other in elasticsearch...

The other different in scoring is the avgFieldLength:

Lucene is right with 14 / 4 = 3.5. Elasticsearch is different for each score result - but this should be the same for all documents...

Can you please tell me, which settings/mapping I missed in elasticsearch to get it to work like lucene?

**IndexingExample.java:**

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.*;
import org.apache.lucene.index.*;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException;
import org.apache.lucene.search.*;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class IndexingExample {
    private static final String INDEX_DIR = "/tmp/lucene6idx";

    private IndexWriter createWriter() throws IOException {
        FSDirectory dir = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(INDEX_DIR));
        IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(new StandardAnalyzer());
        return new IndexWriter(dir, config);
    }

    private List<Document> createDocs() {
        List<Document> docs = new ArrayList<>();
        FieldType summaryType = new FieldType();
        summaryType.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS);
        summaryType.setStored(true);
        summaryType.setTokenized(true);

        Document doc1 = new Document();
        doc1.add(new Field("title", "b c d d d", summaryType));
        docs.add(doc1);
        Document doc2 = new Document();
        doc2.add(new Field("title", "b c d d", summaryType));
        docs.add(doc2);
        Document doc3 = new Document();
        doc3.add(new Field("title", "b c d", summaryType));
        docs.add(doc3);
        Document doc4 = new Document();
        doc4.add(new Field("title", "b c", summaryType));
        docs.add(doc4);

        return docs;
    }

    private IndexSearcher createSearcher() throws IOException {
        Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(INDEX_DIR));
        IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(dir);
        return new IndexSearcher(reader);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
        // indexing
        IndexingExample app = new IndexingExample();
        IndexWriter writer = app.createWriter();
        writer.deleteAll();
        List<Document> docs = app.createDocs();
        writer.addDocuments(docs);
        writer.commit();
        writer.close();

        // search
        IndexSearcher searcher = app.createSearcher();
        Query q1 = new TermQuery(new Term("title", "d"));
        TopDocs hits = searcher.search(q1, 20);
        System.out.println(hits.totalHits + " docs found for the query \"" + q1.toString() + "\"");
        int num = 0;
        for (ScoreDoc sd : hits.scoreDocs) {
            Explanation expl = searcher.explain(q1, sd.doc);
            System.out.println(expl);
        }
    }
}
```

**Elasticsearch:**

```
DELETE twitter

PUT twitter/tweet/1
{
    "title" : "b c d d d"
}

PUT twitter/tweet/2
{
    "title" : "b c d d"
}

PUT twitter/tweet/3
{
    "title" : "b c d"
}

PUT twitter/tweet/4
{
    "title" : "b c"
}

POST /twitter/tweet/_search
{
    "explain": true, 
    "query": {
        "term" : {
            "title" : "d"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with the help of [jimczy](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/24429#issuecomment-298562682):

> Don't forget that ES creates an index with 5 shards by default and
>   that docFreq and docCount are computed per shard. You can create an
>   index with 1 shard or use the dfs mode to compute distributed stats:
>   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-type.html#dfs-query-then-fetch

This search query (dfs_query_then_fetch) worked like expected:

```
POST /twitter/tweet/_search?search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch
{
        "explain": true, 
        "query": {
                "term" : {
                        "title" : "d"
                }
        }
}
```